# How to parse this string in Python using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse this string to get the total active, idle and down nodes 'Total Nodes: 259  (Active: 226  Idle: 33  Down: 0)' in Python. I am doing it using spaces, but it is not the most efficient way, what would a regex expression to extract the information for the string look like

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding service.  Detail what output you expect, what output you got, and the code that's causing the problem.  "parse" is not specific.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far? What kind of "information" are you trying to extract, exactly? Investigate the python re library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Looks like `\(Active: (\d*) Idle: (\d*) Down: (\d*)\)` groups 1,2,3 every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple Solution

You can extract the numbers only into a list, if they are always in that order and never more or less numbers per string (and integers) with this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Total Nodes: 259 (Active: 226 Idle: 33 Down: 0)'
    'Total Nodes: 259 (Active: 226 Idle: 33 Down: 0)'
>>> y = re.findall('(\d+)', s)
    ['259', '226', '33', '0']
```

## Robust Solution

Here is how we can turn that into a dict. This is in Python 3

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Total Nodes: 259 (Active: 226 Idle: 33 Down: 0)'
    'Total Nodes: 259 (Active: 226 Idle: 33 Down: 0)'
>>> s = '{' + s.replace(')', '').replace('(', '') + '}'
>>> temp = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z][^:]+)', r'"\1"', s)
>>> temp = re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'\1,', temp)
>>> dict_of_vals = eval(temp)
```

This leaves you with a dictionary contain the values you want. this will still work for more than 4 numbers, and order no longer matters

Comment: If the order is not guaranteed, just convert everything to list and the wanted number will be next to the wanted word. Better yet, convert to dict.

Comment: @alvits Ye,s that's the way to do it. OP didn't say it would be in any other format, so I'm showing him the simplest solution to the problem. If you see this OP, do as he suggested and make a dict if your order/length isn't guaranteed.